# Adding multiple domains to one application

Tags: php, dns, nameservers

I am creating an application that is basically a simple website builder. Now I would like to map domain names to this application, so the URL will be:

http://www.customdomain.nl/contact/

instead of

http://www.websitebuilder.com/customdomain/contact/

How can I do this?

Comment: Depends entirely on your web-server. If apache, look at vhosts. This is not a programming question as such, so is not suitable for SO. If you add more details about your server setup and what you have tried, it **might** be suitable for ServerFault